# Using the Weak-Law of large numbers

Tags: probability

Consider two sequence $X_n,Y_n$ of random variable with Bernoulli distribution ($p=0.5$).
Let $Z_n\:=\:max\left(X_n,Y_n\right)$.
How to calculate $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{Z_1+Z_2+..+Z_n}{n}\right)=?$$

So far what i did is like this:
I calculated the expectation of $\frac{Z_1+Z_2+..+Z_n}{n}$ and i got this: $$E\left[\frac{Z_1+Z_2+..+Z_n}{n}\right]\:=\:\frac{1}{n}E\left[Z_1+Z_2+..+Z_n\right]\:=\:\frac{1}{n}\left(E\left[Z_1\right]+E\left[Z_2\right]+\:...\:+E\left[Z_n\right]\right)\:=\:\frac{1}{n}\left(E\left[\:max\left(X_1,Y_1\right)\right]+E\left[\:max\left(X_2,Y_2\right)\right]+\:...\:+E\left[\:max\left(X_n,Y_n\right)\right]\:\right)$$ 
and because $X_n,Y_n$ are both Bernoulli with $p=0.5$ it doesn't matter which one of them is the maximum, so i continued and i got:
$$=\:\frac{1}{n}\left(0.5+0.5+...\:+0.5\right)\:=\:\frac{1}{n}0.5\cdot n\:=\:0.5$$

And by using the *Weak law of large numbers* i conclude that $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{Z_1+Z_2+..+Z_n}{n}\right)=0.5$$
But i think i'm missing something important in the calculations here..it's even true what i did? can someone give any feedbacks? tnx a lot in advance!

Comment: Hint: $EZ_i=\frac34 \times 1 + \frac14 \times 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your $X_n$'s and $Y_n$'s are all supposed to be independent.  Assumptions such as this are important, and should be stated.

Note that $\max(X_n, Y_n) = 1$ unless both $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are $0$, in which case it is $0$.  So
$E[\max(X_n, Y_n)] = 3/4$, not $1/2$.